# Which programming languages implement the concept of a function inverse, such as names() in R

Tags: r, functional-programming, computer-science

In the R programming language, some functions can either return a value, or they can *set* that value if an assignment is made to them. In the below example, we create a named list, and use the names() function to get a vector of those names:

```
> ll <- list(x = 1, y = 2, z = "whatever") # create a list
> names(ll)
[1] "x" "y" "z"
```

But I can use the same function to set those names, in a very interesting way. I *assign* a new vector to the exact same form as above:

```
> names(ll) <- c("a", "b", "c")
> names(ll)
[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

Is there some kind of quirky R magic going on here? Or is this a technique in computer science which one can see in other (esoteric?) languages? I'm interested in DSLs and this idea appears quite powerful and I'd like to research it further. It's as if you're saying "give me the input to the function such that the output is this".

This doesn't work but imagine it did:

```
> f <- function(x) x + 1
> f(2)
[1] 3
> z <- 3
> f(z) <- 2
Error in f(z) <- 2 : could not find function "f<-"
> z
[1] 3
```

I wanted z to be equal to 1, because f(1) is 2.

This idea maps closely to the concept of an inverse function in mathematics. Not all functions have an inverse, of course, but since programming often has mathematical underpinnings,  I wonder if the concept is explored further in any other programming languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Generalized references - Common Lisp

Your first example is more about the concpet of *lvalues* in C/C++, and in the case of Common Lisp, *places*. [Generalized references](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/05_aa.htm) are based on macroexpansion and can be extended by the programmer.

Let's say you build a cons cell `(cons 0 1)`, and let's say it is bound to a local variable named `x`. A cons cell is just a small structure with two slots, with accessors `car` and `cdr`. For example, `(car x)` is 0 and `(cdr x)` is 1. Typically, lists are built by chaining cons-cells where the `cdr` is a sublist.

The historical way to mutate the slots is by calling [`RPLACA/RPLACD`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rplaca.htm) functions (*replace car*, *replace cdr*). The SETF exapansion mechanism is a way to talk about *places* and how to affect them. In the case of cons-cells, you have two writer functions whose names are `(setf car)` and `(setf cdr)`; the names are literally lists of two elements (this is the only case where a function name is not a symbol).

Then, you can write `(setf (car x) 2)` to mutate `x` so that it holds the value 2. This is macroexpanded as a call to `RPLACA` by setf-expansion.

Other macros are built on top of `setf`, and generally are named with a `-f` suffix, like `incf`:

```
(incf (cdr x))
```

The above increments the value of the CDR of X.
`setf` also trivially works for setting local variables.

What is interesting is that the mechanism can be composed; the accessors for hash table is `(gethash <key> <table> &optional <default-value>)`; the accessor for arrays is `(aref <array> ... <subscripts>)`. You could write:

```
(setf (aref (gethash key table) index)
      new-value)
```

And the above would change the value at position `index` in the array associated with `key` in `table`.

The composition is efficient, because the expansion only traverse the nested data-structures down to the point where the structure shall be modified; For example, if you mutate a tree `tree` equal to:

```
(root-node (node-a 0 1) (node-b 2 3))
```

Then the value 2 is the first child of the second child of the root node, which in terms of list positions is written as follows:

```
(second (third tree)) 
=> 0
```

If you want to increment that value, you write:

```
(incf (second (third tree)))
```

And `INCF` is clever enough to only traverse the list once; this is the result of macroexpansion:

```
(LET* ((#:LIST (CDR (THIRD TREE))) (#:NEW (+ 1 (CAR #:LIST))))
  (SB-KERNEL:%RPLACA #:LIST #:NEW))
```

This mechanism can be extended by calling [`define-setf-expander`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defi_3.htm); For example, the [`Cells`](https://github.com/kennytilton/cells) library implements a kind of constraint propagation mechanism, like spreadsheets formula (dataflow, reactive programming), where the change in an object's slot value is propagated down to users of that slot value (http://stefano.dissegna.me/cells-tutorial.html). But for users, it is only a matter of calling `(setf (slot object) value)`, which abstracts the underlying magic.

#### Constraint programming - Prolog

Prolog and more generally constraint programming are notorious for allowing relationships to be called in mutliple directions (example with https://eclipseclp.org/ interpreter):

```
lib(fd).
f(X,R) :- R #= X + 1.
```

Case where `X` is ground and `R` left variable:

```
[eclipse 3]: f(3,R).

R = 4
Yes (0.00s cpu)
```

Case where `X` is variable and `R` ground:

```
[eclipse 4]: f(X,4).

X = 3
Yes (0.00s cpu)
```

Case with both being left variables:

```
[eclipse 5]: f(X,Y).

X = X{[-10000000 .. 9999999]}
Y = Y{[-9999999 .. 10000000]}

Delayed goals:
    -1 - X{[-10000000 .. 9999999]} + Y{[-9999999 .. 10000000]} #= 0
```

Case where both are ground:

```
[eclipse 6]: f(5,10).

No (0.00s cpu)
```

Comment: Ha! I had sneaking suspicion that Prolog would allow this! I'm going to parse this answer in depth and am very glad to hear that I wasn't completely crazy. I'm interested by why you characterize Prolog's ability to look at this as "notorious" as opposed to say, "impressive". As for the LISP side I asked for a computer science answer, and boy did I get one. Give me a few months (years?) to get up to speed. Just starting on Racket. Awesome. Duly answered many thanks.

Comment: @ThomasBrowne Thanks a lot for the kind words!

Comment: This is also a common feature of computer algebra languages such as [Wolfram](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseFunction.html).

Answer (score 2):

I am by no means an expert in R syntax, but coming from a Java/OOP background, I can explain your obervations with the following:

```
> ll <- list(x = 1, y = 2, z = "whatever") # create a list
> names(ll)                                # call the getter for list names
> names(ll) <- c("a", "b", "c")            # call the setter for list names

> f <- function(x) x + 1                   # define a function
> f(2)                                     # call the function
[1] 3
> f(3) <- 2                                # makes no sense
```

That is, when `names(object)` appears by itself or on the RHS of an expression, R will call the getter for the names of the object.  When it appears on the LHS of an assignment, R will call the setter, using the values on the RHS.

Trying to assign a value to result of a function call makes no sense.  A function is generally a stateless thing, and so we should not expect anything other than what you saw.

Comment: Perhaps my terminology is imperfect. "Reciprocal" perhaps might be called "inverse". Mathematical functions often (but don't always) have inverses. So some programming languages should have it? It's a mathematically sound concept. 

 I'm wondering which programming languages support this. I suspect Prolog might do so because of its logic programming paradigm, but I'm not expert enough to know.

Yes of course I could just define a bunch of functions, which is essentially what you're doing in OOP, and then hiding them nicely. But that's not really mapping to the semantics of the question.

Comment: The thing is, functions in R do not have any memory or storage of which to speak.